# Java EE xml beans

Tags: spring, java-ee-6

Is it possible to define beans in Java EE the same way you can in Spring via XML config files.

In Spring I can take a POJO

```
public class ClickCounter {

private int count;  
public int getCount() {return count;}  
public void setCount(int count) {this.count = count;}

}
```

and define the bean in xml

```
<bean id="clickCounter" class="com.clickcounter.ClickCounter">
</bean>
```

Comment: I believe EJB 3.1 uses a POJO model and DI now.  They learned a lot from Spring and Hibernate.  No surprise since Rod Johnson and Gavin King were on the committee.

Answer (score 0):

It is, just create an emtpy beans.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

And then create your bean:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
@Singleton
public class MyBean{
}
```

Comment: But the beans.xml file is empty, and you are annotating your classes. Is it possible to do it without using annotations?